# Access contacts in Android for work application

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-for-work

I have a application which shows list of Contacts and then some actions in them. 
When this app installed as "Android for work" it cannot get contact list.

Is there any way or some other API to get this. I am not trying to get Contacts which are outside work profile. I am interested in "Work Contact" app.

I tried **ENTERPRISE_CONTENT_FILTER_URI** API to get contacts.

Comment: Does this solve your problem: https://developer.android.com/work/contacts

Comment: I read the same. But it talks about normal app accessing Contacts from work profile. I want app to run in work profile and get access to work contacts.